# Formal notation of group count

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I want to write down following group count operation. I am creating variable in dataset called *countpd* equal to count of observation points grouped by variables *countid* and *day*. *i* stands for observation point number. Is logic in the attached equation correct?

$countpd_i=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{B_j}$

where $B_j = \{ pid=pid_i \wedge day=day_i \}, j=\{1,2,...n\}$

Comment: The image is too small to read the subscript easily, can you edit it into your question as a formula?

Comment: Sure, done. Sorry, at first wasn't aware how editor handles latex expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, you can write count in terms of sums of indicator functions, [Inverson brackets, or Kronecker deltas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326537/how-to-write-down-formally-number-of-occurences). The only problem with your notation is that you index $B_j$ by $j$ and then, inside of your definition $j$ does not appear anywhere, so it is not clear what is the $j$ index. It is hard to suggest better notation without knowing your problem in greater detail, but you would need to tell your readers what $j$ index is about, e.g.

$$
\mathrm{countpd}_{j} = \sum_{i=1}^n  [ \mathrm{pid}_i = \mathrm{pid}_j \,\land\,  \mathrm{day}_i = \mathrm{day}_j ]
$$

Comment: Thank you. Let me make sure that I understand the logic corretly. If I would to apply similar grouping, but on lagged variable $day$ lagged, would following equation be correct?
$countpd_j=\sum_{i=1}^n[pid_i=pid_j \wedge day_i = day_{j+1}]$
Or should I rather specify double indexation given 2 variables tham I'm grouping on like:
$countpd_{p,d}=\sum_{i=1}^n[pid_p=pid_p \wedge day_d = day_{d+1}]$

Comment: @Aleksander I'd rather use the second formulation. In the first one it is unclear that $j+1 = i+1$, i.e. it is a lagged variable. But this *really* depends on your problem and what you are aiming to show. My point is: make the indexing explicit.